# IAP or integrating PayPal?

Tags: in-app-purchase

In the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies), it states that any apps selling digital contents must utilise the use of IAP; while apps selling physical goods or services used outside of the app must utilise other payment mechanisms (e.g. PayPal).

For my situation, which one (IAP/external payment) should I use?

My business is selling used cars. I have a website and an iOS app. Users using my app can post an advertisement about their cars and the ads would be appeared on my website too.
In simple words, ads posted from any one platform will be appeared on the other.
Posting ads is not free and we charge them some amount of money.

So which payment should I use? Is it a service used outside of the app? To be honest I don't want a 30% cut from Apple it's too much..